# What are name of Tai chi 108 form Wu style in Cantonese?

Tags: tai-chi

I would like to know the name of 108 form, tai chi Wu style, in cantonesse

Comment: They are all listed at at [108-form Wu family tai chi chuan - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/108-form_Wu_family_tai_chi_chuan)

Comment: Are you sure it’s cantones ? Or Chines ?

Comment: @DavidPostill From the wording of the entry I get the impression that these are the names in *Mandarin*, not *Cantonese* while the question explicitly asks for a name in Cantonese if there is one. I cannot speak to the appropriateness of that assessment though.

Comment: Are you looking for a Romanisation or for the traditional Chinese symbols?  If I recall correctly mandarin is usually written in simplified Chinese while Cantonese is usually written in traditional Chinese.  That said any symbol in traditional Chinese will have both a Mandarin and Cantonese reading.

Answer (score 2):

#### I would like to know the name of 108 form, tai chi Wu style, in Cantonese

The 108 forms of the Wu family style of T'ai chi ch'uan are listed at
[108-form Wu family tai chi chuan - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/108-form_Wu_family_tai_chi_chuan).

> For each unique form name there is a literal translation, the Hong Kong school's translation and then the Shanghai school's translation in italics where they differ, followed by the original Chinese characters.

Example:

> 1. Begin T'ai Chi Form - The Beginning of T'ai Chi - The Preparation Form 太極起式